# Where to find a custom error message in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, error-handling

[image: Custom error message]

I'm running a stored procedure in SQL Server and I'm getting the above error. I assume that this is a custom error because it is business-specific and also the word "because" is misspelled. But this text does not appear in the stored procedure text. Where can I find this error message so that I can determine why it is appearing?

Comment: Q: So how are you invoking the stored procedure????  Q: Can you show us the procedure?  ALSO: Look here - [PRINT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Does this stored procedure invoke any other procedure ?

Comment: paulsm4 - From the screenshot, I have just right-clicked the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio and then clicked "Execute". This error message is also returned to the application itself if I try to run the process from within the application.

Comment: rootkonda - It does invoke another stored procedure but the error message does not appear in that stored procedure either.

Comment: Have a look in [`sys.messages`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/messages-for-errors-catalog-views-sys-messages?view=sql-server-ver15).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is most likely a custom error message in the `sys.messages` table. Look for either the `THROW` or `RAISERROR` that is using a message id greater than 50000. That should tell you where the error is coming from and also you can correct the spelling mistake.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I found the error on sys.messages and then when I Ctrl-F'd "RAISEERROR" in the procedure text I found it immediately. Thank you!